# What makes running so much less energy-efficient than bicycling?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, everyday-life, efficient-energy-use

Most people can ride 10 km on their bike. However, running 10 km is a lot harder to do. Why?

According to the law of conservation of energy, bicycling should be more intensive because you have to move a higher mass, requiring more kinetic energy to reach a certain speed. But the opposite is true.

So, to fulfill this law, running must generate more heat. Why does it?

Some things I can think of as (partial) answers:

- You use more muscles to run.
- While running, you have more friction with the ground; continuously pouncing it dissipates energy to it.
- While you move your body at a slow speed, you need to move your arms and legs alternately at higher and lower speeds.

Comment: Simplistically speaking, cycling puts more energy, including your own vertical movement, into horizontal movement, while running has that irritating waste of pushing energy into the ground vertically

Comment: also important to note, your question assumes a flat surface. One can run further up an incline from a standing start than someone who cycles up the same incline from a standing start

Comment: Don't forget the mechanical advantage a bicycle's drivetrain offers.

Comment: It is a common misconception that energy is required to keep mass moving. There is not such law of physics. There is an opposite law, which says that mass keeps it velocity unless you (de)accelerate it with force (and energy). It is friction which dissipiates energy and bycicle may only add to it. Otherwise, there is a much stronger question: why do you get tired when keep heavy weight in your hands? According to the laws of physics, table does not loose any energy  when you put the weight on it (despite another misconception).

Comment: @Val That's an interesting comparison in fact. Is there a question/article about that?

Comment: @StevenRoose: I've seen the answer in Feynmann lectures or something. He told that most of the animals have the "fast muscles" that loose energy all the time, when stressened. There is moving something inside muscles all the time, despite they move nothing: the force they exert is just to counterbalance the gravity. Meantime, there are "slow muscles", like molluscs and pythons have. Nothing is moving inside them and, thus, they are never get tired. They look as strong as the stone.

Comment: I don't think you understand kinetic energy. You do not have to continuously supply energy to an object to maintain its kinetic energy (except to replace what is lost by drag or friction).

Comment: One more factor everyone's missing--when you're running you have to pick up your trailing leg and move it forward.  This takes considerable energy even when you're moving at a constant velocity and the bicyclist is expending little energy.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One word: inertia. When you're riding a bike on a level gradient you just need to give it a push to get going, then you can coast for quite a while before friction and air resistance slow you down. In other words, the relatively frictionless wheels mean the bicycle's kinetic energy doesn't dissipate quickly. But the human body doesn't have wheels, so while running you have to give a good kick to get going, and then another kick to keep going on the next step, and so on. When hills are involved the difference is even more pronounced, since we run downhill the same way we do on the level, by continually pushing ourselves forward; whereas on a bicycle you can take advantage of the slope and just coast down it.

I suspect that raising and lowering your centre of mass isn't as inefficient as the other answers have suggested. This is because your legs are springy, so at least to some extent you're just converting energy back and forth between gravitational potential and the spring force in your legs. Humans are possibly the most efficient long-distance runners in the animal kingdom. There is a school of thought that says the reason we are bipeds is that we evolved as endurance hunters, chasing our prey until it collapsed from exhaustion rather than trying to outrun it over short distances. Whether that's true or not, we probably wouldn't do all that bouncing up and down if there wasn't a good reason for it.

You might ask why, if using wheels is so much more efficient, didn't we evolve that instead? I don't know, but it seems no animal has been able to evolve wheeled locomotion.

Comment: No animal ever evolved wheel locomotion because there was never an environment where wheeled movement would be beneficial. Nature lacks a specific important aspect that benefits wheeled movement. Roads / flat surfaces.

Comment: WRT your last remark. "[S]imply put, a complex structure or system will not evolve if its incomplete form provides no benefit to an organism." "Molecular biologist Robin Holliday has written that the apparent lack of biological wheels argues against creationist or intelligent design accounts of the diversity of life—for, free of the limitations imposed by evolution, an intelligent creator would be expected to deploy wheels wherever they would be of use." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_locomotion_in_living_systems#Biological_barriers_to_wheeled_organisms).

Comment: I know that there are several theories on why wheeled locomotion hasn't evolved. My money's on a combination of the "incomplete form" argument @Gugg mentioned, together with the difficulty in connecting up blood vessels, nerves etc. around a continuously rotating joint. (I think the "lack of roads" argument isn't a great one, because wheels have their uses offroad as well.)

Comment: From what I read, we evolved as bipeds because walking on two legs instead of 4 uses less energy. This in turn allowed our brains to grow because they had more energy available to them.

Comment: Wrong on all counts. Wheels do _not_ store energy. Legs are _not_ very springy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Pistorius)

Comment: @Nathaniel yes wheels do have use off road, but now put an animal with wheels on a rough and rocky incined surface, and a human with two legs. Place a hungry tiger behind them, and tell me which one would be able to survive. Wheels outclass movement only on flat surfaces, the required energy to maintain large offroad wheels would not benefit a living organism in any way

Comment: I would also like to see a wheeled animal climb a tree or swim, its not a benefit on anything but perfect conditions

Comment: @sds thanks for pointing out the bad wording regarding energy storage - I meant that wheels allow kinetic energy to be stored by reducing friction, so that it doesn't get dissipated. I'll edit it to make it clearer. Pistorius' prosthetics are springier than your average human ankle, but that doesn't mean human legs aren't springy at all.

Comment: There is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_spider that has evolved wheels.. kindof.

Comment: @sds Well, kangaroo legs are pretty springy, but the fact that they are an exception points up your claim in general.

Comment: @Jens that's awesome. Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4odlo0Afjs) of it. (Rolling starts at about 1:10.) But I'm not sure whether I'd count it as a wheel unless it's joined by an axle to something that doesn't rotate...

Comment: VSauce on YouTube has a great video on why there are [no animals that have wheels](http://youtu.be/sAGEOKAG0zw).

Comment: Let me point out that humans are BY FAR the worst long distance runners. (And they're the worst short distance runners too.) Four legged animals have thin legs, because each leg has to carry less weight. Hoofed animals walk on their nails, their legs are mostly tendon, thus thin; the muscles are close to the body, so the legs can move fast. (Example: deer). The bipedalism of humans is a HUGE disadvantage. Early hominids can only have been scavengers. Humans catch prey with snares, with nets, with a coral, or with a weapon. Chasing is useless; all potential prey animals outrun humans by far.

Comment: Rubbish, there are tribes which traditionally hunt by outrunning animals on the plains and it's a battle of endurance.  The beast collapses from exhaustion.

Comment: @Cleonis - you should do a little more research on this. Most other animals are much better sprinters, but it is definitely true that humans are one of the best long-distance running animals, and there's a lot of research to suggest that being bipedal helps with this. There's also no evidence that species before Homo Sapiens had tools more advanced than sharp sticks, such as the snares and nets you mentioned. The popular theory is exactly as Nathaniel suggested, that we evolved as persistence hunters.

Comment: @RhysW similarly, for trivia, jellyfish evolved [a toroidal locomotion system](http://fox.rwu.edu/jellies/flowrowing.html) because that kind of ['wheel'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_ring) can exist in a natural fluid environment.  (c.f. [models](http://udini.proquest.com/view/an-algorithm-for-fully-resolved-pqid:1934128821/) and [experiments](https://www2.lirmm.fr/lirmm/interne/BIBLI/CDROM/ROB/2010/DETC_2010/data/pdfs/trk-2/DETC2010-29053.pdf)

Comment: @Jens similarly humans can do cartwheels which make us both legged and wheeled animals

Comment: To the wheeled locomotion thing, make sure you don't forget about bacterial flagella! (yes, I know it doesn't really 'count' for various reasons)

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy on a similar note, there's also the [ATP synthase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_synthase) molecule in every cell of our bodies. Continuously rotating joints are not so uncommon on the molecular level, it's only in the macroscopic world that we don't really see them.

Comment: @RhysW I agree, a wheeled animal would not be well adapted to life on rocky inclines, up trees, or in water. But then, neither is a giraffe. You're absolutely right that wheels aren't as generally versatile as legs, but nevertheless if wheeled animals did exist I suspect there would be ecological niches they could occupy.

Comment: @Nathaniel agreed, there is a niche for everything. It wouldn't surprise me if life on another planet had the right conditions to produce this kind of animal

Comment: @RhysW: In the book _The Amber Spyglass_, there is a description of a species in an alternate universe, which has developed a symbiosis with a certain tree. The tree produces large, hard nuts, and this animal hooks onto the nut with a claw and uses it as a wheel. Long-term usage of the wheel breaks it, scattering the seed. Not happened on Earth, but sounds plausible.

Comment: Btw, guys, could we move this to a chatroom? I'd be glad to help in moving stuff over if needed.

Comment: @Manishearth I found something better than a chat room: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/7932/3395.

Comment: @Gugg: great :)

Comment: @Nathaniel, according to wiki, there are some animals that have evolved to roll. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_locomotion#Rolling

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why it is easier to cycle *uphill* (where coasting is ineffective) than to walk or run.

Comment: The problem with wheeled animals: how would you connect the veins and arteries to it? Wheels are wearing so you must constantly feed it to make it regrow, and it must be connected to some tissue. It should be able to rotate freely, but this cannot be possible because the tissues would twist and tear... 

On the other hand, what's the point of having wheels if you don't have roads to run on?

Comment: I have heard the estimate that humans, although (in the wild) fantastically good distance runners, aren't that efficient at converting the lost potential energy from bobbing up and down (about 5%) - although this effect is small (we run so that there isn't much bobbing up and down - that's how we solve the problem). Cheetahs and kangaroos, very alike in their locomotion, do bounce a great deal and the recovery is 90% efficient. Also, the same theory about our distance running you cite is also the most plausible I've heard yet for why we lost our hair.

Comment: For wheels: why not two organisms in a symbiotic relationship?: the host feeds the wheel organism when stationary! (Not really relevant I know)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal that's kind of an amusing image - I like it - but it's hard to imagine how the two organisms could conspire to exert a continual torque on the axle without running into the same problems a single organism would have...

Comment: @Nathaniel Agreed: I can't see either how the arrangement would drive itself directly through the wheels as you say: they would either have to be used simply to efficiently coast, or the whole pair organism could propel itself like a snakeboard or ripstick.

Comment: this answer is only slightly correct (actually does not explain why the difference in efficiency since same average speed shoud be maintained), see my answer as well

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance My car and I have a symbiotic relationship. I feed it, and it transports me. Humans evolved that way...

Comment: @Floris LOL :) That's a wonderful way of looking at things!

Comment: I don't believe this is the right answer. Even when you simulate with a cycling robot, you don't realize that the robot's joints are made of cogs that massively reduced energy waster by joints' friction by turning friction into static friction. Even if it is true that inertia is the answer, you need a better argument and evidence to support it.

Comment: *The human body doesn't have wheels that can store kinetic energy, so while running you have to give a good kick to get going, and then another kick to keep going on the next step, and so on.* This makes no sense. Bike wheels are light. In both running and cycling, the main KE is the KE of the person's body moving forward.

Comment: *When hills are involved the difference is even more pronounced,* This is contradicted by experiment. Minetti et al. have shown that elite trail runners running on uphill slopes of $>0.20$ have an efficiency that is equal to the efficiency of concentric muscle contractions. This is also the efficiency of cyclists going up a steep hill.

Comment: @BenCrowell your first comment has been pointed out before. I meant of course that having wheels enables energy to be stored in the form of kinetic energy of the body moving forward. The post is from 2013 and I don't really have the will to edit it, but you of course are welcome to. Regarding your second comment, that doesn't contradict what I said at all. Note that my comment on hill is more about going downhill than up.

Comment: Better late than never, I fixed the misleading "wheels that store kinetic energy" bit.

Answer (score 22):

> Many of  us have ridden  bicycles at
>   some time in our lives. and in fact
>    this mode of transportation has become
>   markedly more popular recently as a result of the energy
>   shortage.  Each morning at  my own
>   university, Duke, people can be
>   seen riding machines with masses
>    of $10$ to $20$  kilograms and struggling
>   to  reach one  of the  campus entrances
>   at the top of a long,  steep hill.
>   As in  many other aspects of animal
>    locomotion, there is a paradox here.
>   Why should people  encumber
>   themselves with such  heavy apparatus,
>   particularly while  going uphill?
>   Ask  a rider this  question, and
>   the response is usually: "It's easier
>   than walking" or "It's faster than
>   walking." But  why should it be?
>
> A number of incorrect  explanations
>   are offered: "A bicycle  has gears."
>   Shifting  gears allows the rider to
>   vary the  speed at which the feet
>   move; but even if  the foot speeds  of
>   a cyclist and a pedestrian are
>    matched, the cyclist still goes farther and in  less time on a  given
>   amount of  energy than the pedestrian.
>   "Your  weight is supported by
>   the seat." But if you pedal  standing
>   up, biking still is faster and less
>    costly of energy than going  on foot.
>   "Your center of gravity doesn't go
>   up and down." But it  does if you
>   pedal standing up. Why, then, is
>   bicycling easier than walking  or
>   running?
>
> […]*
>
> We can now appreciate why bicycle
>   riders are willing to propel  the
>   extra weight of a bicycle, even
>   when going uphill. The cost of
>   transport on a bicycle is low because active muscles are  not
>   stretched while  pedaling, and mean
>   muscle  efficiency is about $.25$, nearly
>   its maximum value. The wheels
>   stabilize the rider's  center of mass.
>   Even if the rider  accelerates the
>   center of mass vertically by  pedaling while standing up, active muscles
>   need not be stretched.  When
>   the center of mass falls, the cranks,
>   sprockets, chain, and rear wheel
>   constitute a system of  levers that
>   transposes the vertical motion to a
>   horizontal  one by supplying a perpendicular
>   force.  Thus, humans can
>   use external machinery to move
>    along a level surface with the same
>   muscular efficiencies that swimming and flying animals achieve
>   naturally.

[*The Energetic Cost of Moving About: Walking and running are extremely inefficient forms of locomotion. Much greater efficiency is achieved by birds, fish—and bicyclists. V. A. Tucker,
American Scientist,
Vol. 63, No. 4 (July-August 1975), pp. 413-419*](http://www.zianet.com/wrucker/the%20energetic%20cost%20of%20moving%20about.pdf)

---

*Of course, most of the article is where I put "[...]". It's quite a good, fun read. There's even some kind of Galilean experiment with dropping [pigeons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flying%20rat) and rats from heights.

Comment: "active muscles are not stretched while pedaling". That is the exact crux of the issue. I am sorry to see this did not become the top voted answer. See also [an answer to a duplicate question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137885/26969) - I think we agree...

Comment: There is at least one error in Tucker's analysis, which is in his discussion of efficiency compared to the maximum efficiency of muscle contractions. He says that efficiency when pedaling a bike is close to the maximum efficiency of muscle contractions. He seems to imagine that this maximum is never achieved without a bike, but that's not the case. In steep uphill running and walking, the same efficiency is achieved. See Minetti, J Physiol 471, 725, 1993; Minetti, J Exp Biol 195, 211, 1994.

Answer (score 11):

- **Bicycles make better use of inertia/momentum.** As Nathaniel said, one push and you can coast for quite a while. That's just not possible while running.
- **Running wastes energy moving up and down.** In addition to moving forward, running requires a substantial upward push to get your body airborne, giving you time to bring your other foot forward. You then cushion and spring forward and upward again. While bicycling does have an up-and-down component to the pedaling, because the bike doesn't leave the ground, the energy you use in pedaling is converted much more efficiently to forward motion.
- **Bicycling can translate weight to propulsion.** While most serious bicyclists will tell you that pedaling is about spinning, not stepping, any 10-year-old can tell you that going butt-in-the-air and transferring your weight from left to right gets you going pretty quickly.
- **Pedaling with toe clips makes use of the entire leg motion.** When your feet are locked to the pedals, it isn't just the pushing-down portion of the pedal stroke that is used; lifting your foot, pulling it forward, pushing down and pushing backward all keep tension on that chain and so add power to the stroke. When running, fully half of your foot's cycle is wasted energy from a forward-motion perspective.
- **Bicycling gives you mechanical advantage.** Even with a single-gear bike, the motion of your foot is magnified when translated to the wheel. On a multi-speed bike, the ratio of the top gear is pretty high indeed. This allows two things; first, your effort is magnified, and second, your tempo slows, which reduces the amount of energy wasted moving the weight of your legs around.

Comment: The last three points of this answer make no sense when speaking about energy-efficiency...

Comment: Are you kidding? All three of them have a profound effect on energy-efficiency of bicycling versus running. You can bicycle as fast as jogging (at least) just by straightening your leg and shifting your weight to one foot, using that weight to push the pedal down, then shifting your weight to the other leg. The "entire leg motion" point specifically states how it's more efficient than a running stride, and the mechanical-advantage point says when the motion does more work, the percent of energy spent moving the weight of your own legs versus pushing you forward is lower (aka more efficient).

Comment: Agree with Steven Roose. High gears only waste

Comment: Steven Roose is right: the last three points are no good in this context, where we're concerned with the overall energy requirement. Cycling sitting down, without toe clips, in a low gear takes less energy than walking: therefore, standing up, toe clips, and high gears can't be the explanation.

Comment: forget friction at joints? (foot-to-ground, ankle, knee, hip) Remember that running on easily deformed surfaces (like sand or soft ground) makes people tired a lot quicker even when the deformation after each step is small.

Comment: *Running wastes energy moving up and down.* The net work done by gravity per cycle is zero for both running and cycling. *Bicycling can translate weight to propulsion.* This part doesn't seem based on any physical principles. *Pedaling with toe clips makes use of the entire leg motion.* This would not affect efficiency. It would affect power. It might also have an effect on endurance, because it makes use of the muscle glycogen stored in the muscles that lift the leg. But we're discussing efficiency here.

Comment: *Bicycling gives you mechanical advantage.* A mechanical advantage has no effect on efficiency. Simple machines don't change the amount of work done.

Answer (score 8):

- Running requires intense muscle contractions with a low duty cycle, whereas cycling uses long, smooth contractions. If you work at running, you can easily get to the point where it is no longer an aerobic challenge, yet still tough: you hardly have to breathe, yet the legs struggle with lactic acid buildup.
- Running wastes a lot more energy on compensating motions: the runner has to move her torso and arms to compensate the kicking motion of the legs.  The leg motion is not symmetric in running: the forward kick of the recovering leg is faster than the backward movement of the drive leg, and so the arm on the same side as the recovering leg has to swing backward to compensate its motion.  Compensation on a bike is mostly limited to a side-to-side rocking during a hard effort.
- The runner basically flies through the air, but periodically comes down and touches the ground with one foot, and then exerts a force in order to get back up into the air. However, this is not done by an efficient, elastic bounce. The landing energy is dissipated, rather than stored and reused. In fact, the runner must exert energy in order to absorb the landing, and then exert more energy to get back into the air. The runner thus wastes considerable energy to stay in the air.
- Depending on the nature of the footstrike, the runner may counter-productively be exerting energy which retards (brake) his forward motion, and then has to exert more energy to recover momentum.

Comment: *Running requires intense muscle contractions with a low duty cycle, whereas cycling uses long, smooth contractions* No, this is wrong. Elite runners typically do 90 stride cycles per minute. Elite cyclists typically do 70-90 revolutions per minute.

Comment: *If you work at running, you can easily get to the point where it is no longer an aerobic challenge, yet still tough: you hardly have to breathe, yet the legs struggle with lactic acid buildup.* This is wrong. All running events at distances of about a half mile or greater (2 or more minutes) are aerobically limited.

Comment: @BenCrowell Middle distance running (half mile to three miles or so) is aerobically limited only in those trained/talented athletes whose bodies can actually develop the output that requires the oxygen supply: they are able to run these distances at their VO2Max. Secondly, it drops off with increasing distance; past 3 miles or so, racing isn't done at VO2Max.  Whether it remains aerobically challenging depends again on the individual. The ordinary recreational runner is severely limited by their lactate threshold, so when they run distances, it's nowhere near their aerobic capacity.

Comment: @BenCrowell Elite athletes are a tiny, cherry picked minority, not a statistically unbiased population sample.

Comment: @BenCrowell The muscle contractions in running are much shorter and more intense than those in cycling, at equal stride counts.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the answers here go into movement of your center of gravity etc. I think it's a lot simpler than that.

When you are cycling your vertical movement on the pedals is translated into horizontal movement of the wheels, coupled with inertia a small amount of energy can go a long way.

Whereas whilst running you are putting energy into moving horizontally, to get places, as well as vertically to reduce friction with the floor. However all the vertical movement is fighting gravity, and wasted as your vertical movement gets you no closer to your destination

This answer assumes that the distance is over a flat surface. As soon as you throw a three dimensional aspect on it then the system turns on its head.

For horizontal movement the bike is best as its wheels are designed to reduce friction, unlike feet.

However as soon as you come to an incline the lack of friction will cause the bike to roll backwards unless constant energy is put in to the system, whereas the increased friction one has from running allows anyone to stop and stay put.

As soon as you get to an incline from a standing start, running is much more efficient than cycling.

Comment: *whilst running you are putting energy into moving horizontally, to get places* While you're running, the time-averaged change in your KE is zero. *However all the vertical movement is fighting gravity* Gravity does zero net work over the course of one stride on level ground.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest to understand if you start by considering the extreme cases of steep uphill and downhill slopes.

Actually it isn't true in all cases that running is less efficient than cycling. In work by Minetti et al. ("Energy cost of walking and running at extreme
uphill and downhill slopes," DOI 10.1152/japplphysiol.01177.2001.), it was found that when elite mountain runners run uphill on a treadmill, at slopes greater than about 0.20, the efficiency becomes about 0.25, which is the efficiency of concentric muscle contractions. ("Concentric" means that the direction of motion is in the same direction as the contraction of the muscle, as when you do a pull-up.) This is an upper limit on the efficiency of any human-powered mode of going uphill, so since trained runners achieve it, they are not less efficient than cyclists on these slopes.

On a steep downhill, a cyclist can coast while the leg muscles expend zero energy. Running downhill does consume energy. In fact, the runner's efficiency is negative, because the gravitational potential energy of the person's body decreases, while the body's energy reserves are depleted. Minetti measured the downhill efficiency on grades steeper than $-0.20$ to be $-1.20$, and this is approximately the efficiency of muscles in eccentric contraction (like letting yourself down from a pull-up).

So if we can understand why lowering yourself down from a pull-up expends energy, then we automatically also have a physiological explanation of the imperfect efficiency of downhill running on the steepest grades, and then by interpolation we have an explanation of why running is less efficient than cycling on ordinary slopes or on the flats.

The reason that muscle tissue expends energy in eccentric contractions is that there are processes in the body that dissipate heat when a muscle is under tension. For example, the body has to burn fuel to maintain muscle tension, and there is also internal friction in the muscle as the muscle moves.

In addition to the processes described above, there are other energy-dissipating mechanisms as well, including the dissipation of energy into vibration and sound on a runner's foot strike.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Nicks answer, when you run, you sort of jump a little bit so that you raise your center of mass, which costs you energy equal to

$$\Delta E = m g \Delta h$$

Now when you lower your center of mass, the energy is dissipated as the vertical acceleration gained by going down is not increasing your horizontal speed.

This is definitely one of the causes.

Also, one can think about dissipated power, which might give us more insight. For example we have the following identity:

$$ P = \cfrac{\operatorname{d} W}{\operatorname{d} t} = \vec{F} \cdot \cfrac{\operatorname{d} \vec{x}}{\operatorname{d} t} = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$$

Also, let's assume, that power losses in both cases are similar and that the input power is the same in both cases (we use similar muscles in both cases after all).

Now we have the velocity very different in both cases, and we could probably also agree, that there is much more force produced if we run as we can speed up to our maximum speed very quickly. So far everything agrees with the formulae.

Now we can easily convince ourselves, that even if the efficiency is similar in both cases, the loss of energy in running would be greater because we do it for longer for the same distance travelled.

Comment: *when you run, you sort of jump a little bit so that you raise your center of mass, which costs you energy...Now when you lower your center of mass, the energy is dissipated as the vertical acceleration gained by going down is not increasing your horizontal speed.* You seem to be assuming that the vertical and horizontal motions decouple, but I see no reason to believe that's true.

Comment: After this, you give a completely separate argument about power and speed. This model makes incorrect predictions. It predicts that cyclists and runners should have the same efficiency at the same speed, which is false on flat ground. It also predicts that the energy required to run or bike a certain distance should be a monotonically decreasing function of the time, but actually there is an optimal time. I use much more energy sprinting 100 meters than walking 100 meters.

Comment: In your use of the identity $P=Fv$, you also haven't specified what force or what power you have in mind. If you're running or cycling in a straight line at constant speed, the time-averaged net force on your body is zero. And the power that's of interest as a physiological limit on performance is not the power delivered as mechanical work (which is ordinarily zero on the flats), it's the rate at which energy dissipated from the body's supply of fuel. If you're running downhill, the power delivered as mechanical work is negative, while the body's rate of energy expenditure is positive.

Answer (score 2):

It's down to the biological inefficiency of maintaining the mechanical constraint of one foot stationary with regard to the floor, with the rest of the body moving.

Let's suppose a skater on ice and another on rollers use approximately the same amount of energy to get to say 5 km/s. Both possess a different, but efficient compared to walking, mechanism that maintains that velocity, while satisfying any mechanical constraints. For the one on rollers, the point of contact between the ground and a roller must be stationary. For walking, the foot in contact with the ground must be stationary, and the biological mechanism for this introduces far greater biological losses.

However, there are far more efficient modes of biological transport such as [hopping](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1986-01-19/news/0190220124_1_kangaroos-hopping-animals) as in the case of Kangaroos, which uses half the energy of a marathon runner. Kinetic energy is converted into potential energy in the tendons while the mechanical constraint is maintained, with most converted back into kinetic energy upon leaving the gound.

Comment: *It's down to the biological inefficiency of maintaining the mechanical constraint of one foot stationary with regard to the floor, with the rest of the body moving.* This doesn't make sense. A bike's wheel is rolling without slipping, so the tire is at rest relative to the ground as the bike is moving, just like the runner's foot while it's on the ground. Both the bike-body system and the runner's body have parts that decelerate and accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess would be that for running you are lifting your centre of mass with every step while with cycling your centre of mass has a constant height.  Therefore you are only doing work against air resistance/friction in the bike mechanics.  While running you are also working against gravity.

Comment: You're working against gravity in a wasteful way: not like an elastic bouncy ball which stores energy and comes back to almost the same height, but more like a sack of rice.

Comment: This explanation doesn't work. When you run on level ground, you're lowering your legs just as often and as much as you're raising them, so that the net work done in gravitational PE is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the underlying mechanism which transforms the chemical energy into kinetic energy of the vehicle or body. The answer is that the bicycle mechanism (due to having wheels etc..) is able to transform this energy better.

A classic analog is the lever or a pulley. One can use a lever or a pulley to lift a weight which would be very difficult (or even impossible) to lift with bare hands.

So to maintain same average speed with a bicycle one needs to use less chemical energy (than running) and as a result produce less heat.

> "*Give me a place to stand and I can move the earth*"

-- [Archimedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes) on the principe of the lever (allegedly)

A [related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/143494/44176) on the principle of the mechanical lever (and variations)

Comment: Does this sound kind of strange to you: Assuming that the people don't even move their center of gravity and that the only parts that have gravity on them during pedaling are the light weight legs. In that case, cycling is still less tiring. Archimedes' words on the lever do not mean the energy used is better. You have less force but longer distance in that case. At higher value of force, the structural integrity of your soft body starts breaking down making the energy spread to doing the structural deformation. You get more tired, and you get tired quicker.

Comment: *The answer is that the bicycle mechanism (due to having wheels etc..) is able to transform this energy better.* This isn't an explanation, it's just a statement of the definition of efficiency. The question is why the efficiency is different. *A classic analog is the lever or a pulley. One can use a lever or a pulley to lift a weight which would be very difficult (or even impossible) to lift with bare hands.* No, this is wrong. The mechanical advantage provided by a simple machine doesn't affect the amount of work done, so it has no effect on the efficiency.

Comment: *So to maintain same average speed with a bicycle one needs to use less chemical energy...* This is a non sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

As there are already answers which explained it very well, we can have an analogy to understand it further.

[image]

Consider that square wheel is us and round wheel is cycle. Now let's try to rotate the square wheel. When you do, a normal force will act from the right edge of the wheel instead of center to prevent it from toppling. (Torque will act in opposite direction and stop it from rotating). So the only possible option is to pick this wheel in air and put on next step.

But in case of round wheel, normal reaction always act at the bottom most point of the wheel and torque because of the normal force will always be zero. So there is no force acting on the round wheel to stop it's rotation. Because of this once a round wheel is given a push, will keep on rotating without any further force. (As there is no opposite force acting).

Now if we compare both wheels, picking up a wheel and putting down on each step will always be more energy consuming or will require more work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reasons are:

1. We have heavy legs designed more for climbing or slow walking where they can swing like a pendulum.
2. We have to start & stop our legs using our muscles, whereas the crank on a bicycle recycles the momentum like the crankshaft of an engine recycles that of the pistons.
3. Our muscles do not recycle energy fed back into them. In other words, we don't have regenerative braking. We actually waste a bit of energy bringing something to a stop, pushing it, or holding it up without moving, a bit like the resistance losses (copper losses) in an solenoid actuator.
   While muscles are efficient, we don't use them efficiently when running.